# Grails 3 production version stylesheet displays different than develpement version

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to deploy the grails 3 web app using war command. Development version shows proper style sheet and after deploying on production server its just messes everything up .as css and JavaScript are minified i cant really figure out the problem ....example in the image development version [image: development version]
production version
[image: Production version]

I am using above code to display tab and below css..

```css
#tabsF {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#efefef;
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:normal;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}
#tabsF ul {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 10px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none
}
#tabsF li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;


}
#tabsF a {
    float:left;
    background: url(../images/tableftF.gif) repeat-y;;
    margin: 1px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 4px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#tabsF a span {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background: url(../images/tabrightF.gif) no-repeat right top;
    padding:5px 15px 4px 6px;
    color:#666;
}
/* Commented Backslash Hack hides rule from IE5-Mac \*/
#tabsF a span {float:none;}
/* End IE5-Mac hack */
#tabsF a:hover span {
    color:#FFF;
}
#tabsF a:hover {
    background-position:0% -42px;
}
#tabsF a:hover span {
    background-position:100% -42px;
}

#tabsF #current a {
    background-position:0% -42px;
}
#tabsF #current a span {
    background-position:100% -42px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabsF">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab1"><span> &nbsp;Viewer1 &nbsp;</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: 'Jobque', action: 'viewer2')}"><span>&nbsp;Viewer2 &nbsp;</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: 'Jobque', action: 'viewer3')}"><span>&nbsp;Viewer3 &nbsp;</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Minified files are really hard to debug, but there is probably just a syntax error somewhere.  I don't see anything immediately obvious, but using the developer console in Chrome (probably firefox too, but I just know Chrome), you can try un-minifying the related files and just compare them visually to see if you can spot the error.  It will probably be something minor when you finally find it, like a missing semicolon or an order of attributes problem that the minifier enforces a bit too strictly.

Comment: #tabsF ul {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 10px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 10px; LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none
}

try changing that to lower case that doesn't appear to be correct syntax as  in is it really `PADDING-TOP` or is it `padding-top` ?  don't think all those entries are valid

Comment: @vahid Thanks it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

- You can see the CSS rules in Firefox developer tools for chrome developer tools
- If you want you can disable the css/js minifation as shown below. And build the war and see if the issue still exists that way you can make sure if its the problem with minifaction or problem with your code. And once u have isolted and fixed the problem enable it again.

  ```
  //build.gradle
  assets {
      minifyJs = false
      minifyCss = false 
  }
  ```

Comment: minifyJs = false this didnt help ..it still create the minified version of javascript..Is it becuase i hav asset pipleline syntax in jsp?